# How to turn string into a location for android?

Tags: android, string, geolocation, location, android-studio

I have a string of a location in the format of:

```
Location[fused -34,154 acc=58 et=+3d21h29m34s532ms]
```

by doing:

```
location.toString();
```

How would I then go about and convert the string back into a Location object?

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: Why? Just keep the location object around. If you need to pass it around, it's `Parcelable`.

Comment: @323go I put into a string because I send it to my server. Then the app requests it again and needs to convert it back into a location. Perhaps there is a better way of storing the location?

Comment: Ah yes, in that case, you might want to create a machine-friendly version of the location, most likely JSON.

Comment: @323go am using JSON now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up by sending it in a different format and then generating the location again using longitude and latitude.

Answer (score 0):

this is just info about the location object, because the toString method is not usually overridden by default,

it has **nothing to do with the actual physical location represented by this object**, it is just giving information about this particular object.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#toString()